# Detect a Road Lane and color it RED

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, hough-transform

So.. I'm basically trying to take this picture on the left and outputting it as on the right of the following image:

(Left) Input image, (Right) Output image

[image]

Do you have any suggestions?

This is what I'm trying to do right now:

1. `cvtColor()` to convert to grayscale
2. `threshold()` to detect white areas
3. `Canny()` to select edges
4. `HoughLinesP()`

   ```cpp
   vector<Vec4i> lines;
   HoughLinesP(cannyImg, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 50, 50, 10);
   ```
5. Then I (try to) get the strongest lines from `HoughLinesP` (I'm not sure it works)

```cpp
    sort(lines.begin(), lines.end(), compareLength);

bool compareLength(Vec4i line1, Vec4i line2)
{
    double length1 = sqrt(pow(line1[0] - line1[2], 2) + pow(line1[1] - line1[3], 2));
    double length2 = sqrt(pow(line2[0] - line2[2], 2) + pow(line2[1] - line2[3], 2));
    return length1 > length2;
}
```

6. I save all the points of the two lines in an array

   ```cpp
   for (int i = 0; i < 2 && i < lines.size(); i++)
   {
       auto line = lines[i];
       arr.push_back(Point(line[0], line[1]));
       arr.push_back(Point(line[2], line[3]));
   }
   ```
7. I use a function that I wrote to draw an entire row of the picture in red between two Points (that must be on same y coordinates)

   ```cpp
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i += 2)
       src = drawRedLine(src, arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
   ```

where:

```cpp
Mat drawRedLine(Mat img, Point p1, Point p2)
{
    Mat res = img.clone();

    if (p1.y != p2.y) // if points are on same y cord
    {
        cout << "Error: Points are not on the same row" << endl;
        return res;
    }

    if (p1.x > p2.x) // if p1 is on the left of p2
        swap(p1, p2);

    for (int x = p1.x; x <= p2.x; x++)
        res.at<Vec3b>(p1.y, x) = Vec3b(0, 0, 255);

    return res;
}
```

This doesn't work (probably because I don't select the right lines from `HoughLinesP`). But anyway, I feel like there is a better way to do all of this without going that low-level.

So... Feel free to give even completely different solutions (or ideas).

Comment: semantic segmentation? use AI for that. the newbie traps (canny, hough, ...) make absolutely no sense here. no sense at all.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz and without using AI?

Comment: I think there are many research papers about "lane detection".  So search and read them at frist may be good way for you.